# Number of ways to decompose a graph into two trees

Tags: graphs, trees

Is there an efficient algorithm to count how many ways there are to decompose a given finite simple undirected connected graph $G = (V, E)$ into the union of two trees $T_1 = (V_1, E_1)$ and $T_2 = (V_2, E_2)$ that are not necessarily edge-disjoint? By union I mean $V = V_1 \cup V_2$ and $E = E_1 \cup E_2$. My initial thoughts:

1. $V_1$ and $V_2$ cannot be disjoint, so $|V_1| + |V_2| > |V|$.
2. $|V_1| + |V_2| \geq |E| + 2$ because $E_1 \cup E_2 = E$ and $|E_i| = |V_i| - 1$.
3. If $G$ is a tree then we are counting the number of ways to write $V = V_1\cup V_2$ where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are not disjoint. This can be presumably calculated analytically.

Comment: 3. It's not that simple. Consider tree $1-2-3$: you can't split it as $(1,3)$ and $(2)$. While you do can compute the answer for the case when $G$ is a tree, it's by no means trivial. Currently, I'm not sure it's possible to do this for general graphs efficiently. We can use property 2 (it must hold $2|V| \ge |E| + 2$ for any subgraph) to say that the answer is 0 in some cases.

Comment: Your example comprises disjoint vertex sets.

Comment: $1-2-3-4-5$ split as $(1,2,4,5)$ and $(2,3,4)$

Comment: Ah ok understood, thanks!

Comment: @abhi01nat property 1 isn't actually true right? Shouldn't it be $|V_1|+|V_2| > |V|$? Both trees don't have to contain more than half of the nodes only one of them has to.
(I'm criticizing the phrase "so each").

Comment: @plshelp you're right, let me edit that!